# SQL to Schema Model

Tags: .net, sql, xsd

Is there a library out there that can input SQL create/schema statements and construct a XSD or some sort of in memory schema model. Even if it's a DataTable. It needs to have a binding to .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for visual studio 2005 --> you can go for creating TableAdapters.
for visual studio 2008 --> you can add a .dbml file with the complete schema.

Both are most probably same method of tranforming the SQL to Schema model, but with some more customization and reliabilities are available when you use .dbml file, as its a newer version of .net

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but linq-to-sql produces dbml files which are a .net code based representation of your database tables.